# How to select distinct rows when using joint table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named chatMaster and chatMessages , i was trying to left join the two tables to get all data from master and latest message for each chat. I am using this query to join the two tables

```
SELECT  c.id, c.p1, c.p2, m.toP, m.message, m.createdOn FROM chatMaster c
left join chatMessages m on c.id = m.id group by  m.id ;
```

This query is for selecting only one row for each entry in chatMaster, but it is selecting the first message for every entry like,

```
1, 2018-11-24 00:40:08, HI!,       99e22056-ee7f-11e8-bc28-8acac6f59ef9, 1001
2, 2018-11-24 00:40:21, HI! There, 99e22056-ee7f-11e8-bc28-8acac6f59ef9, 1
3, 2018-11-24 01:33:12, HI!,       e3345a17-ee7f-11e8-bc28-8acac6f59ef9, 2
```

this is the result of `select * from chatMessages`, There are two entries for chat id `99e22056-ee7f-11e8-bc28-8acac6f59ef9` and i want the send one which is send on `2018-11-24 00:40:21` but the result of my join query is

```
99e22056-ee7f-11e8-bc28-8acac6f59ef9, 1001,     1,    1001, HI!, 2018-11-24 00:40:08
e3345a17-ee7f-11e8-bc28-8acac6f59ef9,    2, 10001,       2, HI!, 2018-11-24 01:33:12
```

It is selecting the first message. How to select the latest message? What changes should i make to get the latest message from chatMessages instead of first message. please ask if you need more details

Comment: Why are you left joining ? I doubt a chatmaster can exist without any chatmessages in it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Get latest message from 2 tables that are associated with eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361878/mysql-get-latest-message-from-2-tables-that-are-associated-with-eachother)

Comment: Because when a chat request is accepted an entry is made in master table and at that time there will not be any entry in chatMessages

Comment: Check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53391638/2469308 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53090014/2469308

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Do you have access to the version 8.0+ ? Solution complexity will be significantly less in newer versions (with Window functions).

Comment: I'm using 5.7.23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can get the maximum values of `createdOn` (latest `createdOn`) for every chat-master `id`. You can then join this result-set to the main table, to get only the row corresponding to latest `createdOn`.

```
SELECT  c.id, c.p1, c.p2, m.toP, m.message, m.createdOn 
FROM chatMaster c 
LEFT JOIN
( SELECT id, MAX(createdOn) AS latest_createdOn 
  FROM chatMessages 
  GROUP BY id
) AS dt 
  ON dt.id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN chatMessages m 
  ON m.id = c.id AND 
     m.createdOn = dt.latest_createdOn
```